# Android: I need a Numeric Keyboard that can allow the characters "1234567890.,-"

Tags: android-studio, keyboard

I have this in my Edit text

```
    android:inputType="numberDecimal"
    android:digits="0123456789,.-"
```

However, the result is this:
[Keyboard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgu2s.png)

I don't know what is wrong. Please help me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

because `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` won't let you choose any other characters except for 0123456789. You need to change the line  `android:inputType="numberDecimal"` to 
 `android:inputType="text"`

```
android:digits="0123456789,.-"
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you. So that means that I can't have a numeric keyboard with those additional keys, right? If you know any way of doing that please help me. However, your answer helped me a lot.

Comment: I don't think there is any way to do so. If I find some solution, I will surely help you. Don't forget to upvote my answer.